# Preventing wp from removing br and p tags

Tags: html, wordpress

Is there a way to prevent WP from removing br and p tags from posts or pages ?

so far I've added `remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');` to my `functions.php` file which completely disables formatting.

However when i edit a post or page, and in the HTML editor add br or p tags then switch back to visual mod the br/p tags that i added get removed.

Is there a way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 16):

It is not really a solution but a workaround: write your `<p>` tags like this:

```
<p dir="ltr">something</p>
```

This way they are preserved when switching from editors. You can apply this to any text tag. Here you can read about the `dir` attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html

I have noticed that if you try to do the same with `<br>` tags, when you swicht editors WP has replaced `<br>` with a `&nbsp;`. To prevent that, `br` tags can be written like this:

```
<br class="blank" />
```

I am also looking for a definitive solution for this issue and it seems there is none yet, not even with the new Wordpress 3.6 release. Please if anyone knows a better solution I'll be so glad!

Comment: i just want to point out that this is an absolutely horrible out-of-the-box setting by wordpress. a visual html editor should never truncate html unless there is a really good reason to do so and there isnt one here. reinforces my thoughts as a developer that you should never use wordpress unless you absolutely have to

Comment: THX for <br class="blank" />

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code, in your functions.php,

```
function stop_removing_tags(){
    remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
}


add_action('init', 'stop_removing_tags');
```

Code Not Tested ...