# WordPress Shortcode Stripping out Line Break

Tags: html, wordpress, line-breaks

So here is my code, which I'm trying to create some columns in my page.

```
[one_fourth]
<h3>A</h3>
<hr />
<a title="AAF Filter Cross Reference Chart"    href="http://dev.replacementdustcollectorfilter.com/deltamaxx-cartridge-filter-cross-reference/aaf-filter-cross-reference-chart/">AAF</a>
<a title="Aerocology"  href="http://dev.replacementdustcollectorfilter.com/deltamaxx-cartridge-filter-cross-reference/aerocology/">Aercology</a><br/>
<a title="Air Refiner" href="http://dev.replacementdustcollectorfilter.com/deltamaxx-cartridge-filter-cross-reference/air-refiner/">Air Refiner</a><br/>
<a title="Airex" href="http://dev.replacementdustcollectorfilter.com/deltamaxx-cartridge-filter-cross-reference/airex/">Airex</a><br/>
<a title="Airflow Systems" href="http://dev.replacementdustcollectorfilter.com/deltamaxx-cartridge-filter-cross-reference/airflow-systems/">Airflow Systems</a><br/>
[/one_fourth]`
```

Notice the line breaks in the code...when it is published those breaks are gone though, which you can verify at http://dev.replacementdustcollectorfilter.com/deltamaxx-cartridge-filter-cross-reference/.

Comment: It's very common, this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327100/preventing-wp-from-removing-br-and-p-tags

Comment: Please de-activate then activate all plugins once.

Comment: I tried the deactivate, reactivate option and it didn't work. I also tried turning `<br/>` into `<br class="blank"/>` and that didn't work.