# Upload post to WP makes <br> tags disappear

Tags: python, wordpress

I use https://github.com/maxcutler/python-wordpress-xmlrpc to upload articles to `Wordpress`. I noticed that text lines inside `<div>` are automatically wrapped by `<p>` tags and `<br>` tags are removed.

Is there a way to keep `<br>` tags?

```
post = WordPressPost()
post.title = 'title'
post.content = '<div>This is a test article<br><br>There are some linebreaks<br><br>here<br></div>'
post.post_status = 'publish'
wp.call(NewPost(post))
```

Creates this post:

```
<div>This is a test article
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>There are some linebreaks</p>
<p>here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing wp from removing br and p tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327100/preventing-wp-from-removing-br-and-p-tags)

Comment: @Ruvee Thank you, looks good but thshea's comment was enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could whitelist the tags you're interested in. Wordpress has a special function for that:

> [`wp_kses`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/)

In your case, for example, you could whitelist your `<br>` tags like so:

```php
add_filter('the_content', 'your_theme_whitelist_tags');

function your_theme_whitelist_tags($content)
{

  $whitelist_tags = array(

    'br' => array()

  );

  $content = wp_kses($content, $whitelist_tags);

  return $content;
}
```

Which keeps the `<br>` tags and remove other html tags. If you want to keep your `<div>` tags as well, then you could also add that tag in your whitelist array.

Code goes into the `functions.php` file of your active theme.

Let me know if you could get it to work!